# CMakeLists Including OpenGL, glew, glfw, glm and assimp

Tags: linker, cmake, static-libraries, dynamic-linking

I started working with CMakeLists a few days ago and I can't quite figure how to include an external library (.h + .dll/.lib files) to my project and sub projects. Any tips and tricks would be much appreciated!

What I want to do is to include a bunch of external libraries (listed in title) to my projects. Plus I'm not sure if I want to do static or dynamic linking.

This is my current file structure:

[image]

And this is my CMakeList so far...

[image]

As I said, the problem is that I don't quite grasp CMake yet.

Comment: The most important question is if you want this to be cross-platform or not, because as it stands it most likely isn't.

Comment: Yes, cross-platform is important for my project.

Comment: Then I really suggest not to include external dependencies, because then you need to bundle the correct dependencies for each platform, build them as part of your project, or have special cases for platforms that do not have the need for such shenanigans.

Comment: Okey, that is good to know. The question still remains, how?

Comment: This is an important question because there are no standard practices and tools for this in C/C++/CMake world (as opposed to e.g. Maven). There are   many experiments, of course.

Comment: @Edvin, in the question you write you'd like to include external projects as *.h/dll/lib. In the second comment you write cross-platformness is important which contradicts with the h/dll/lib part. Please clarify first, you either need to stick to fixed platforms or build from sources on any platform supported by your dependencies. Both approaches are possible. Which one do you need?

Comment: right... dll/lib files are built per platform right? Or even per individual PC?

So if I want to include an external library I need to download their source files (e.g .h/.cpp files) then build the dll/lib files on my computer and finally link them with my project?

Comment: @Edvin: dll/lib files are usually per-platform (windows/mingw/cygwin), per architecture (32/64) and per compiler (msvc X/gcc/clang). But what I need to know before I can suggest you a solution is that (1) you intend to include or reference the prebuilt binary files (lib/dll) in your project, or (2) include or reference the sources of the external projects, which you will build and install before your main project. All your dependencies are lightweight so (2) is easy, too.

Comment: Okey! Thanks for clearing that up. I think it would be best if I include the sources of the external projects so that anyone could download the project with the external libraries and build them on their computers. The main goal is to create a folder with all the code + libraries that I could zip and send to anybody and let them build it on their computers. Giving them full access to everything and allowing them to modify the code as they please.