# Assimp - Windows - CMakeList - Failing to import

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, assimp, cmakelists-options

I know this question has been asked before (lot of times).

[How to include Assimp with CMakeLists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568147/how-to-include-assimp-with-cmakelists)
[CMakeLists Including OpenGL, glew, glfw, glm and assimp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270457/cmakelists-including-opengl-glew-glfw-glm-and-assimp)

But I still cannot get it to work (normally).

**Question**: How to install Assimp and use with find_package in cmakelist.txt

**What I tried**:

- Made a build with the cmake GUI and then with Visual studio build the
  sln file
- Installed it with vcpck and added the path to
  cmakelist.txt
- add_library(assimp "lib/assimp/assimp.dll")

But all of the methods give errors like: cannot not find assimp, or missing Assimp:Importer

```
include_directories("${LIB_DIR}/assimp/include")
# target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} assimp)


find_package(assimp REQUIRED)
if (assimp_FOUND)
    set(ASSIMP_LIBRARY "assimp")
    add_library(${ASSIMP_LIBRARY} SHARED IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(${ASSIMP_LIBRARY} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${LIB_DIR}/assimp/libassimp.so")
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${ASSIMP_LIBRARIES})
endif(assimp_FOUND)
```

This seems to build, but then I get errors like `unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Assimp::Importer::Importer(void)" (??0Importer@Assimp@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl`

So there is something I am missing entirely and I dont understand it apparently.

Is there something simple I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Does this library come with a `.lib` file?

Comment: It gets created in the cmake+visual studio build step

Comment: When you install using vcpkg, doesn't it install both lib and dll files?